# Explan tcl code

Tags: package, tcl

Can anybody exxplain the following tcl code please :

```
#!/bin/sh
# the next line restarts using tclsh \
exec tclsh "$0" ${1+"$@"}

package require cmdline
package require json

set debuglevel 2

set PWD [file dir [info script]]
set LIB_DIR   "$PWD/lib"

lappend auto_path $LIB_DIR

package require DrupalCurl 0.1

set waoversion 0.1
dputs 4 "loading library version $waoversion"
# load library, initialize basic features
package require waorpm $waoversion

set result [dumpTemplate]
puts $result
```

When i executed the following script manually using the tclsh filename.tcl , i get an output with lots of configurations . dont know how it loads ? And it seems its executing a `waorpm.tcl` from this file .

**/*update for a comment */**

`@Johannes Kuhn` there is a specification for the `waorpm.tcl` file in `lib/pkgIndex.tcl` . thanks .

```
package ifneeded DrupalCurl 0.1 [list source [file join $dir drupalcurl.tcl]]
package ifneeded custcmds 0.1 [list source [file join $dir custcmds.tcl]]
package ifneeded waorpm 0.1 [list source [file join $dir waorpm.tcl]]
```

**But still not getting what `set result [dumpTemplate]` does ?**

Comment: There're two commands you'll have to look up, `dputs` and `dumpTemplate` apparently from the packages DrupalCurl` and `waorpm` respectively.

Comment: Not sure if this helps but I think that you need to execute using the shell environment (bash/korn/c) or remove the top three lines.

Comment: dumpTemplate  is not a tcl command

Comment: Who removed the answer ?!

Comment: look into the `lib` folder for a `pkgIndex.tcl`.

Comment: voluntarily removed by author, it didn't answer the question that you asked .

Comment: Ok, now look into the `drupalcurl.tcl`, `custcmds.tcl` and `waorpm.tcl` if you can find the `dumpTemplate` procedure.

Comment: `dumpTemplate` is not a _standard_ Tcl command, but is rather provided in a package. Probably in the `waorpm` package, given how the code is written. Look in `waorpm.tcl` for information about what it does.